# Scatter plot marker size and legend, markers = area, but how do I get legend labels = diameter?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, legend, marker

I have been a long time viewer of your questions and answers as I learn python.  I have hit a snag in making some figures for a project I am working on.

I am making a figure detailing properties of small bodies in our solar system (asteroids and dwarf planets).

I have successfully created a scatter plot of the small bodies as functions of their orbital period and eccentricity.  Each point marker is scaled in size to the area of the object (diameter**2).  I have created a legend showing these sizes, particularly how they compare to the dwarf planets.

My question:  I do want the marker sizes to scale with the area of the asteroid (as they currently are), but I would like the labels for the marker sizes in the legend to show the diameter.  I am not sure how to have the labels and marker sizes be different relations.  Marker size proportional to diameter**2 and label proportional to diameter.

Here is the code I have so far and the resulting figure:

Small version of my datafile:

```
spkid   full_name   pdes    name    diameter    extent  rot_per GM  e   a   q   i   ad  per per.y
2002060   2060 Chiron (1977 UB) 2060    Chiron  166     5.918       0.3766  13.71   8.544   6.92    18.87   1.85E+04    50.7
2005145   5145 Pholus (1992 AD) 5145    Pholus  190     9.98        0.5705  20.33   8.733   24.63   31.93   3.35E+04    91.7
2005335   5335 Damocles (1991 DA)   5335    Damocles                    0.8658  11.86   1.591   61.61   22.13   1.49E+04    40.8
2007066   7066 Nessus (1993 HA2)    7066    Nessus                  0.5157  24.66   11.945  15.63   37.38   4.47E+04    122
2008405   8405 Asbolus (1995 GO)    8405    Asbolus 66      8.9351      0.6211  18.04   6.834   17.61   29.24   2.80E+04    76.6
2010199  10199 Chariklo (1997 CU26) 10199   Chariklo    302     7.004       0.1677  15.82   13.17   23.36   18.48   2.30E+04    62.9
2010370  10370 Hylonome (1995 DW2)  10370   Hylonome                    0.2439  25.12   18.993  4.14    31.24   4.60E+04    126
2015504  15504 (1999 RG33)  15504                       0.774   9.368   2.117   34.96   16.62   1.05E+04    28.7
2015760  15760 Albion (1992 QB1)    15760   Albion                  0.075   44.17   40.861  2.18    47.49   1.07E+05    294
2015788  15788 (1993 SB)    15788                       0.3212  39.4    26.747  1.94    52.06   9.03E+04    247
2015789  15789 (1993 SC)    15789       328             0.1886  39.74   32.241  5.15    47.23   9.15E+04    250
2015807  15807 (1994 GV9)   15807                       0.0586  43.58   41.031  0.56    46.14   1.05E+05    288
2015809  15809 (1994 JS)    15809                       0.2231  42.54   33.05   14.05   52.03   1.01E+05    277
2015810  15810 Arawn (1994 JR1) 15810   Arawn           5.49        0.12    39.61   34.861  3.8 44.37   9.11E+04    249
2015820  15820 (1994 TB)    15820               6       0.3193  39.6    26.961  12.14   52.25   9.10E+04    249
2015836  15836 (1995 DA2)   15836                       0.072   36.18   33.576  6.57    38.79   7.95E+04    218
2015874  15874 (1996 TL66)  15874               12      0.5824  83.73   34.971  23.96   132.5   2.80E+05    766
2015875  15875 (1996 TP66)  15875                       0.3325  39.4    26.304  5.7 52.5    9.03E+04    247
2015883  15883 (1997 CR29)  15883                       0.2131  46.76   36.797  19.19   56.73   1.17E+05    320
2016684  16684 (1994 JQ1)   16684                       0.0523  44.12   41.811  3.75    46.43   1.07E+05    293
2019255  19255 (1994 VK8)   19255               4.7     0.0307  42.7    41.388  1.48    44.01   1.02E+05    279
2019299  19299 (1996 SZ4)   19299                       0.2603  39.66   29.34   4.73    49.99   9.12E+04    250
2019308  19308 (1996 TO66)  19308               7.92        0.1156  43.53   38.499  27.34   48.56   1.05E+05    287
2019521  19521 Chaos (1998 WH24)    19521   Chaos                   0.1016  45.67   41.03   12.02   50.31   1.13E+05    309
```

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.ticker as tk

class MyLocator(tk.AutoMinorLocator):
    def __init__(self, n=4):
        super().__init__(n=n)
tk.AutoMinorLocator = MyLocator

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=[15,10])

#df = pd.read_csv('sbdb_query_results.csv')
#df = pd.read_csv('sbdb_query_results_ast_gt_07yr.csv')
#df = pd.read_csv('sbdb_query_results_ast_lt_1000yr.csv')
df = pd.read_csv('sbdb_query_results_ast_gt_20yr_lt_1000yr.csv')
df.info(1)     


factor = 100.

dia = df['diameter']/factor
dia = dia[~np.isnan(dia)]

scatter = ax.scatter(df['per.y'], df['e'], marker='.', color='blue', s=dia**2, zorder=2)#relative to Neptune

plt.xscale('log')
#plt.yscale('log')
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.tick_params(which='minor', length=2, color='r')

a = [2.76596,39.236193, 43.335, 45.791, 67.6681]
p = [4.61, 247.92065, 284.81, 307.54, 557.56]
e = [7.976e-2, 0.24421, 0.188740, 0.159, 0.44177]
i = [10.587, 17.150, 28.190, 28.960, 44.187]
name = ['Ceres', 'Pluto', 'Haumea', 'Makemake', 'Eris']
y = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
rcolor = ['orange','violet','cyan','red','lime']

plt.scatter(4.61,7.976e-2,marker='o',s=(939.4/factor)**2, color='orange',zorder=1, label='Ceres')
plt.scatter(247.92065,0.24421,marker='o',s=(2376/factor)**2, color='violet',zorder=1, label='Pluto')
plt.scatter(284.81,0.18874,marker='o',s=(1595.2/factor)**2, color='cyan',zorder=1, label='Haumea')
plt.scatter(307.54,0.159,marker='o',s=(1429.4/factor)**2, color='red',zorder=1, label='Makemake')
plt.scatter(557.56,0.44177,marker='o',s=(2326/factor)**2, color='lime',zorder=1, label='Eris')

legend1 = ax.legend(loc='lower left', scatterpoints=1, fontsize=14)
legend1.legendHandles[0]._sizes = [50]
legend1.legendHandles[1]._sizes = [50]
legend1.legendHandles[2]._sizes = [50]
legend1.legendHandles[3]._sizes = [50]
legend1.legendHandles[4]._sizes = [50]
ax.add_artist(legend1)
legend1.set_title('Dwarf Planets',prop={'size':16})


handles, labels = scatter.legend_elements(prop="sizes", num = 10, alpha=0.6)
legend2 = ax.legend(handles, labels, loc="upper left", fontsize=14, bbox_to_anchor=(0.0,0.25,0.25,0.75), labelspacing = 1.5, borderpad=1.5)
legend2.set_title('Diameter (km)',prop={'size':16})


plt.xlabel("Period of Revolution (years)")
plt.xlim(1,1000)
plt.ylabel("Eccentricity")
plt.ylim(0,1)
plt.title('Small Bodies in Solar System')

plt.show()
```

Comment: What's in `handles` and `labels`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the content of labels. If you print labels, you will see something like this :

```
['$\\mathdefault{8}$',
 '$\\mathdefault{16}$',
 '$\\mathdefault{24}$',
 ...
 '$\\mathdefault{80}$']
```

The numbers inside the '{}' symbol are the numbers which appears in your legend and are equal to square of the real diameter of your data, because you rescaled the diameters. Then you have to extract the numbers in the labels list, apply a square root on them, transform them back to string and build a new labels list with the result. For example:

```
new_labels = []
for ll in labels:
     ll_nbrs = float(''.join(c for c in ll if (c.isdigit() or c=='.')))
     diam = ll_nbrs**0.5
     new_labels.append(str(diam))
legend2 = ax.legend(handles, new_labels, loc="upper left", fontsize=14, 
                    bbox_to_anchor=(0.0,0.25,0.25,0.75), labelspacing = 1.5, borderpad=1.5)
```